# Context mkiv and \cite

Tags: bibliographies, context

In Context MKIV using bibliography produces in just one case an annoying dash. (-Eastwood, 1997). All other footnotes work OK, in Latex all works OK. Some non-standard character?

```
\mainlanguage[english]
\usebtxdataset[default][mydatabase.bib]
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]

\starttext

\startbodymatter

Test.\cite[Eastwood:1997]

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
\startchapter[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]
\stopchapter
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext

% Don't know how to make filecontents in Context, here is mydatabase.bib

@Article{Eastwood:1997,
        title = {Astronomy in Christian Latin Europe c. 500 - c. 1150},
        author = {Bruce Eastwood},
        journal = {Journal for the History of Astronomy},
        volume = {28},
        year = {1997},
        pages = {235-258},
        language = {english},
        hyphenation = {english},
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem you describe cannot be reproduced using the example in the question because it is missing essential information.  The actual problem is with `\setbreakpoints[compound]` and has nothing to do with the bibliographies system at all.  Unfortunately `\setbreakpoints[compound]` was left out in the question completely.  The following [**minimal working** example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) reproduces the problem.

```
\setupbodyfont[palatino,14pt]
\setbreakpoints[compound]
\starttext
Antique astronomy was gradually replaced
by the logic of counting.(Eastwood)
\stoptext
```

[image]

The behaviour is not expected and I think it should not happen.  Therefore I reported this as a bug on the ConTeXt mailing list. https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/093855.html

As a workaround you can simply adapt the definition of the `(` breakpoint before `\setbreakpoints`.

```
\definebreakpoint[compound][(][nleft=3,nright=3,type=5,left=,right=(,middle=(]
\setbreakpoints[compound]
```

---

The way to make `filecontents` in ConTeXt is using a buffer.  The `btx` module can directly read the bibliography from a buffer without having to store intermediate files.  Just append `.buffer` to the name of the buffer in `\usebtxdataset`.

You might also want to add `\frenchspacing` to the title field, to avoid excessive spacing after periods.

To include page information in your citation, you should use the `righttext` key, rather than the `right` key.  For example the `apa` style sets `right={)}`, so when you override `right`, you'll lose the closing parenthesis.

All of this is described in detail in the documentation [Bibliographies the ConTeXt way](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf).

```
\startbuffer[mydatabase]
@Article{Eastwood:1997,
        title = {Astronomy in Christian Latin Europe c. 500 - c. 1500},
        author = {Bruce Eastwood},
        journal = {Journal for the History of Astronomy},
        volume = {28},
        year = {1997},
        pages = {235-258},
        language = {english},
        hyphenation = {english},
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][mydatabase.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]

\setupbtx
  [apa:list:title]
  [command=\frenchspacing]

\starttext

Test.\cite[righttext={p.~236--238}][Eastwood:1997]

\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! "database.buffer" is non-trivial, I did not find it at first. As for the problem, it must be some non-ascii invisible character, because the problem disappears in other files.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin Can you maybe upload the file somewhere, so that we can get an exact bitwise copy of it?  Stack Exchange usually removes non-printable characters when you paste something here.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin As for the `.buffer` extension I wouldn't say it's non-trivial.  
After all it's described in the manual [Bibliographies the ConTeXt way](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BCQiKhPzdMohcfUjR7zMgjDR7dX-gGyX?usp=sharing

Comment: The .buffer extension is described indeed, but I had hard time believing wheter it will still be straight usebtxdatabase[database.buffer] or the buffer needs to be called [buffer][database.bib], especially because I saw something to that effect on the web.

Comment: In my case I had to add \cite[key]) (an extra parenthesis) because the bibliography processor kept losing it (the last parenthesis). This happened in apa, the same happened in aps when citing pages with [right={}] also made the last bracket disappear. I have no idea where the bug is.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin I checked your example.  What you see there is a breakpoint.  I have no idea how that ended up there but if goes away if you remove `\setbreakpoints[compound]`.  So any actual minimal example would be this https://termbin.com/7y9r

Comment: @DmitryStarostin I've also updated my answer.  The closing parenthesis disappears because you're using the wrong field.  You should use `righttext` for page information.  Please read the documentation.  In the future please also make sure that the example you post here actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I got confused by some older advice from the web that is outdated now.